# binary Operator equal

Tags: c#, linq, operators, decimal

I am facing this error 
"The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]' and 'System.Decimal'."
for the first time can any one tell why got this error

Comment: show us some code :-)

Comment: public class user
{
    public decimal?  colA {get;set;}
    public String       colB {get;set;}
}

Comment: show us some more code *in the question formatted nicely*

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the error because you are trying to compare two types that are not the same - one is `Nullable` and one is `Decimal`.

If you are trying to join across the two types, you can either use `.Value` if you know the `Nullable` value won't be null, or cast the other value to `Decimal?`.

Comment: `var ans = (a == b);` returns *true*.

Comment: You are correct. It must be in the context of a LINQ join.